# Lost Harddisk data after creating Bootable disk with it

Tags: 14.04, external-hdd, dd

Today, I tried creating bootable disk(on external harddisk) in ubuntu using the below dd command and it erased all my harddisk's data.

```
dd if=<source> of=/dev/sdb1 bs=<byte size>; sync
```

Is there any way to recover the lost data? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Raman

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar a couple of years back. After I had exhausted the opensource & free  solutions for HDD data recovery, I came across Raise Data Recovery for ext2, ext3, and ext4. http://www.ufsexplorer.com/rdr_ext23.php
Not free, but not all that expensive. The program runs on Windows only (AFAIK) and you will need a separate storage medium for the recovery process.

I got most of my data back, when everything else I had tried had failed.

Comment: This is not necessary. Use GetBackDataNTFS. It is free and effective. You can find the download link [here](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/download/GetDataBack-for-NTFS,0301-33764.html)